# Why does macOS handle screen resolution differently from Windows?

Tags: windows, macos

Apple iMac & MacBook lineup uses high-resolution display branded as "Retina Display" which by default, macOS will set the screen resolution below the native screen resolution. For example on the 13-inch Retina MacBook Pro, which comes with native resolution of 2560-by-1600, macOS will set the default resolution to 1280-by-800 with option to scaled to other screen resolution (1024-by-640, 1440-by-900, and 1680-by-1050) on Settings app.

However, on Windows (including the latest version) screen resolution are by default, set to the native screen resolution with "Scaling" function to increases the elements sizing. For example on a 15-inch laptop, which comes with a Full HD display, Windows will set the default resolution to the 1920-by-1080 with scaling set to 100% but recommended to 125%. Setting a higher scaling in turns result in certain elements displayed blurry.

Hence, why is this case?

Comment: Off-topic, since not a programming question

Comment: You're misunderstanding what's going on on the Mac. The display is actually at its full resolution. The default scaling is 200%. It's displayed as "looking like" 1280x800 because windows are the same visual size as they would be on a 1280x800 screen, but they have twice the linear detail. Everything is drawn more fine-grained.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch my apologies as Stack Overflow new "ask question" feature said that it will automatically post my question to the correct place if it is not code related ... guess the feature is not working correctly yet.

Comment: They use in effect the same mechanism, if you ask for the screen size in a Windows app that you didn't declare to be dpiAware then you get the smaller rescaled size.  The difference is how text is handled, on Windows the text got rescaled *after* it was drawn, that's why it looks fuzzy.  For a [good reason](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering/).  Latest version of Win10 however also supports the kind of scaling that macOS does: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/

Comment: @HansPassant Great explaination, however for some reasons i personally don't see what wrongs with text on macOS as a graphics designer it looks more appealing to the eyes. But yeah, on Creators Update the scaling got fix in some parts but is still far from perfection. Hopefully it gets better in future releases.

Answer (score -1):

An operating system can work without screens. You could for example start your computer (either running Windows, or MacOSX, or Linux), and run some application `app` (or `app.exe` on Windows) on that command line.

Now, imagine you type `app` (without the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key) in some command window, unplug your screen, and type the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. You `app` has still started (and perhaps detected that no screen is available, only if that `app` is a GUI application opening a window by using some [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)). If your `app` is not a GUI application but a command line one (eg `cp` which copy files) it can successfully execute.

In practice, your screen is today used by some [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server). And your application don't show *directly* pixels on the screen: it interacts with your display server which generally is the only process accessing the screen (more precisely, your graphics card).

So you need to **learn how to tune or configure your display server.** And that of course is **operating system** and display server **specific**. On MacOSX and and Windows and on Linux they are *very* different (and Linux even has *several* ones, e.g. `Xorg` or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))). On MacOSX it is [Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Compositor).